# How to add subdomain for Area in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, subdomain, area

I have a web application using asp.net MVC and have multiple Areas:

> - localhost
> - localhost/admin/home/index
> - localhost/tech/home/index

How can I add a subdomain for this Areas? example:

> - localhost
> - admin.localhost/home/index
> - admin.tech/home/index

Comment: Modify `MapRoute` configuration to include subdomain pattern, note that the modified route should be placed above default one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :), you can give me detailed examples?

Comment: Have you want to use redirect for subdomains? I see that `admin.localhost/home/index` may redirect to `localhost/admin/home/index`, which requires redirecting and URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

```
// admin.localhost/home/index
    [RouteArea("Admin", Subdomain = "admin", AreaUrl="Home")]
    public class SubdomainWithAreaUrlController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("");
        }
    }
```